# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

Seems like such a simple fix but the fixes I've found seem to either be outdated (react 14-) and didn't work or there may be another variable idk.

I'm just trying to keep my Firebase variables out of my GitHub Repo.

- I have 2 env files in my root folder. .env and .env.local

**My firebase Config:**

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_APP_ID
};
```

**My .env.local** :

```
REACT_PUBLIC_API_KEY=AIzaSypgnwErnpfynpyGFPHFfnnfdr8zQjQjlI-pl_THN84
REACT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN=spt-tpghgp.firebaseapp.com
REACT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID=spt-tpghgp
REACT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET=spt-tpghgp.appspot.com
REACT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=1093848932398
REACT_PUBLIC_APP_ID=1:1062445498:web:e664555336e96f249f
```

(numbers of course edited) - Getting the error on process not found.

**My Dependancies:**

```
 "firebase": "^9.9.4",
 "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
 "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
 "react-intersection-observer": "^9.4.0",
 "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
 "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",

"devDependencies": {
   "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
   "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
   "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
   "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
   "sass": "^1.54.8 -watch scss:css",
   "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
   "vite": "^3.1.0"
}
```

Comment: How are you bundling/running your project? Unlike node, the browser doesn't have a `process` global builtin, you need to manually provide it somehow. Most bundlers, like Webpack, provide some utility to do this for you at build time, such as [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#root).

Comment: It's a Vite/React app. I think the issue might be because the application was created through Vite but I'm still unsure of how to fix the issue.

Comment: Vite uses `import.meta.env` instead of `process.env`, see [Env Variables and Modes | Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html).